# Assign pointer in method to subclass C++

Tags: c++, pointers, subclass

So I have a C++ function to which I pass a pointer to a base class, like:

```
void DoStuffAndAssignPtr(MyBase* ptr)
{
    MyBase* p;
    //do stuff
    if (stuff was awesome) p = new MyAwesome();
    else p = new MyBase();
          //vftable of p before the return is MyAwesome
    (*ptr) = (*p);
}
```

Now we need to invoke some virtual method that 'MyAwesome' and 'MyBase' implement differently. However, when checking the return value, as below:

```
void mainly()
{
    MyBase* passMe = new MyBase();
    DoStuffAndAssignPtr(passMe);
    //now passMe is always being returned with MyBase's vftable
}
```

We can see that 'passMe' is always a 'MyBase' (as far as the vftable shows while debugging in VS). Can anyone provide any guidance as to why this is happening, and how I can ensure that 'passMe' will invoke 'MyAwesome' implementations of virtual methods?

Comment: Polimorphys work with pointers and references, but here (*ptr) = (*p);
 you copy by value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the use of `(*ptr)=(*p)`. You should use `ptr=p`.

Only pointer and reference have polymorphism. When you use dereference (the star *), you lose this property, and only the base part is copied from `p` to `ptr`. This is because `ptr` only have space for that part of information.

Comment: Accepted for info about pointer polymorphism gotcha. Solved using different approach but utilized your information. Thank you!

Comment: But that only changes `ptr` in the function. If you want to modify the pointer being passed into the function you need to pass it by reference: `MyBase*& ptr`

Answer (score 3):

You have object slicing issue, below statement slices MyAwesome object to MyBase:

```
(*ptr) = (*p)
```

You only pass `MyBase*` to DoStuffAndAssignPtr and tried to allocate a new pointer which will only overwrite the copy of function parameter.  You need to pass the reference of the pointer instead.

```
void DoStuffAndAssignPtr(MyBase*& ptr);
                                ^^^
```

Also as passMe is allocated by new outside DoStuffAndAssignPtr already, you created another membory for ptr inside DoStuffAndAssignPtr which will cause memory leak.

A better solution is:

```
MyBase* MakeAClass()
{
   if (stuff was awesome)
   {
       return new MyAwesome();
   }
   return new MyBase();
} 

int main()
{
  MyBase* passMe = MakeBase()
}
```